# How do I get the top X results for each type in a Solr index

Tags: search, solr, faceted-search

I have a Solr index with a `type` field that can have different values like "Movie", "Book" and so on. Given a search term, how can I find the top X documents for all the types in my index?

For example, if I search for "cats" I'm looking to get the top X Books, the top X Movies, and so forth about "cats."

I wanted to see if this can be done in a single query, rather than making multiple queries for each of the types. (The types are predefined, about half a dozen in total, by the application using Solr).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted. Its a valid question. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You should check Field Collapsing / Result grouping in Solr. Here is the official documentation. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping

In your case the query Might look like this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/your_index/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=your_field1,your_field2&q=your query here&group=true&group.field=type
```

The results inside the group are by default sorted by score of the query. See `sort` and `group.sort` under **Request Parameters** section in the above documentation.

Comment: I tried the above and it didn't produce any different results, (that is, with separate groups of documents). After a little bit of digging around, I think the version of Solr used with our application is too old to have this feature (1.4, not my decision!). I couldn't find any references to `group` in the 1.4 documentation that I had or any books covering 1.4. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can apply a patch - this will make sure you do not have to upgrade solr - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597972/best-practice-of-field-collapsing-in-solr-1-4  How to apply a patch: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Working_With_Patches